# Using integration to find volume of tetrahedron

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have been trying to solve this question for a while, and I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

The question is

> Find the Volume of a Tetrahedron with vertices $(1,3,5),(0,0,0),(a,0,0),(0,b,0)$.

Every time I try to find the equation of the plane to find the bounds for the integral, the $a,b$ disappears. Just doing it using geometry, I know it should be $\frac{5ab}{6}$, but I am getting crazy answers if I try to do triple integrals.

Thank you.

Comment: You should show what you've tried using triple integrals. Probably it will be easy for someone to see what you did wrong. Otherwise, we have to just guess what you might possibly maybe got wrong, and that's not very productive.

Comment: For every z find the triangle and integrate from 0 to 5 for z

Comment: The title specifies that the problem should be solved using integration, but the question doesn't. Please clarify.